# jira-python getting custom field's value from an issue-link

Tags: python, python-jira

I'm trying to get the value of an **issue link's** custom field.
I know how to do it in a regular sub-task, but with issue-link, I can't get it.

This is how I get a custom field's value in a Sub Task:

```
getattr(issue.fields, name_map[fields[0]])
```

And when I try it with issue link, like this:

```
getattr(**issue_link**.fields, name_map[fields[0]])
```

I get: **AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'customfield_18697'**

What's interesting, I can update the custom field's value, like this:

```
issue_link.update(fields={name_map["Field1"]:"ABC"})
```

Why can I update but not **get the value**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use the code formatting for code and outputs

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Get-custom-fields-from-linked-issues-with-Jira-API/qaq-p/1148453

Needs to be done with a rest call, and not through the API